# Can master pseudoterminal (pty) have more than one slave ptys associated with it?

Tags: linux, terminal

I was studying about pseudo terminals in Linux. My understanding of pty pair was that master pty can have one slave pty associated with it whose file descriptor we can get from **ptsname** system call. But, I came across to this description [link](https://github.com/xemul/criu/blob/e77d36c375ce4ea4fb2f5c22d949fa58766879fb/criu/tty.c#L58) and I got confused about the possible number of slaves, a master can have.

If master would have more than one slave then how will ptsname decide, which file descriptor should be returned, out of all connected slave pseudo terminals?

Also, if more than one slave can exist then how master will interact with each pty? I mean, if a process writes on master fd, will it appear on each slave?

I searched man pages also but there is nothing clearly mentioned that master can have more than one slave or not. Also, about I/O interaction between one master and multiple slave scenario.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the description in the link correctly, a master with several slaves is a sort of unintentional fluke, and you can get this only by bypassing `openpty` and opening `/dev/pts/*` nodes directly, because the following `/dev/pts/*` nodes just get the same master reference internally.

I would expect `ptsname` to return the first slave that was chosen when opening the master. It would be an interesting experiment to find out what happens when writing to a master with several slaves: Does it only write to the first slave (expected) or all the slaves (unexpected)?

I haven't seen any application where there is a master with several slaves.

And BSD pseudoterminals are clearly always pairs, so I don't think this was intended.